# Binary_Checksum Vs HashBytes function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-performance, checksum, hashbytes

I have a complex query which uses a lot of binary checksum function, when I was testing it with some test data for two distinct records it actually returned me same checksum value. Please find the test data I used below

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(16   ,'EP30461105',1) AS BinaryCheckSumEx UNION ALL
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(21   ,'EP30461155',1) AS BinaryCheckSumEx
```

Now I am trying to use HASHBYTES function with 'MD5' algorithm for which I can be certain to get unique records, but what concerns me now is that in the current query I use the 'Checksum' value to join in my 'Merge' statements to look for new records. Since 'HashBytes' returns me Varbinary data type how much of a performance overhead I can expect when I replace the join conditions with the 'HashByte' field.

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONCAT(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,..))
```

And moreover I need to create hashing for multiple columns in which case I need to have an additional Concat function will this have additional overhead to my performance.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That functionality is product specific.

Comment: A checksum is not a cryptographic hash and is not useful for uniquely identifying data. Also consider the hash of `concat('abc', 'd')` & `concat('a', 'bcd')` will be the same.

Comment: Are you positive the query without hashing - i.e. one that can be optimised and leverage indexes is actually less efficient than hashing and comparing?

Comment: @AlexK. I am quite certain that I will not expect such concat scenario of multiple columns when concatenated returning the same value.

Comment: @AlexK. The main reason why we are trying to use a hash or a checksum value is to use it in a merge statement to find if any new record (based on a group fields in target table) is created. If I switch to HashBytes I would have to update the join condition field from 'int' to 'varbinary' how much will this impact my performance is my query.

Comment: Instead of using concat(Colums1, Column2), You should use always concat(Colums1, '|', Column2). In this case you don't have the problem of concat('abc', 'd') & concat('a', 'bcd')

Answer (score 8):

Here are the options:

1. Using index on hash as VARBINARY

   - It’s not a good idea. check these links:
   - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/35b61bb0-1fa8-4a2f-a9fb-729a1874dcf8/clustered-index-on-a-varbinary-column?forum=sqldatabaseengine
   - [SQL Server indexing - varchar(100) vs varbinary(100)? [convert data]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540749/sql-server-indexing-varchar100-vs-varbinary100-convert-data)
2. Using BINARY_CHECKSUM and CHECKSUM

   - It’s good but the problem is there is a high chance of duplication in checksum and as you google you see that many people have a problem with it.

> However, there is a small chance that the checksum will not change.
>   For this reason, we do not recommend using CHECKSUM to detect whether
>   values have changed unless your application can tolerate occasionally
>   missing a change. Consider using HashBytes instead. When an MD5 hash
>   algorithm is specified, the probability of HashBytes returning the
>   same result for two different inputs is much lower than that of
>   CHECKSUM.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788(v=SQL.100).aspx

3. Casting HASBYTES to BIGINT and having index on that

   - It’s not a good idea

> I would also be careful about converting the hashed value to BIGINT
>   given that BIGINT is only 8 bytes yet all hash algorithms -- even MD5
>   -- are greater than 8 bytes (MD5 = 16 bytes, SHA1 = 20, SHA2_256 = 32, and SHA2_512 = 64). And converting binary values larger than 8 bytes
>   to BIGINTsilently truncates the values. Hence you lose accuracy and
>   increasing occurrences of false positives. The following query shows
>   this behavior:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),      --  7 bytes = 72057594037927935
       CONVERT(BIGINT, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),    --  8 bytes = -1
       CONVERT(BIGINT, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),  --  9 bytes = -1
       CONVERT(BIGINT, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) -- 10 bytes = -1
```

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154945/index-maintenance-for-varbinary

4. Casting HASHBYTES to VARCHAR and having index on that

   - This is the good choice
   - You have two options:

a) If you're using SQL 2008 or above

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', CONTENT),2)
```

b) If you're using SQL 2005

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', CONTENT)), 3, 32)
```

PS: If you wonder which Hash Algorithm you should use:

```
MD5 = 16 bytes
SHA1 = 20 bytes
SHA2_256 = 32 bytes
SHA2_512 = 64 bytes
```

[image]

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2011/08/26/data-hashing-in-sql-server/

For your second question, you should make Hash columns PERSISTED, to avoid the impact on running each query.

Comment: Regarding #1: Using index on hash as VARBINARY - What if you use BINARY? ... Hashbytes returns fix size result so binary(16) is enough for an MD5 hash result. Wouldn't it perform better than any of your options listed above?

Comment: The source from the 2nd point is for `CHECKSUM` function. Shouldn't it be linked to [`BINARY_CHECKSUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms173784(v=sql.100))? Maybe the caveat you mentioned about the "high chance of duplication" also need to be updated accordingly.

Comment: @user2286046 Hi, Thanks for your comment. The same logic applied to `BINARY_CHECKSUM` .  just google `binary_checksum duplicates`
I updated the 2nd option to clarify

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but if you are mentioning about [this article](https://dba-presents.com/index.php/databases/sql-server/166-forget-about-binary-checksum-in-sql-server), I think they are wrong. They used `BINARY_CHECKSUM` for `nvarchar` type, but this is clearly mentioned in [this official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): `BINARY_CHECKSUM supports any length of type varbinary(max) and up to 255 characters of type nvarchar(max).` Thus, `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is a valid option for `varbinary`.

Comment: @user2286046   Based on the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you sent:
`However, this change isn't guaranteed, and so to detect whether values have changed, we recommend use of BINARY_CHECKSUM only if your application can tolerate an occasional missed change`

Comment: You are right. I'm Sorry for giving misinformation.